# How to increase the size and height of view by dragging the view from the corners in UITapGestureRecognizer in iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I am doing the project in which I have to show one Image, when I click on the image one "white view "will come on the upper side of the image. And when I double click on the  "two pins" will come out on the "white view". When I pull these two pins the width and height of the white view increase and decrease.

I am not able to do this.

Any Idea from experts would be highly welcome.

```
Second_View.h file

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Second_View : UIViewController<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>{


UITapGestureRecognizer *tap;
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe;
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;
CGPoint startLocation;
CGFloat lastScale;
CGFloat firstX;
CGFloat firstY;
CGPoint lastLocation;


UIImageView *imageVw;
}


@property (nonatomic)  CGPoint center;

@property (nonatomic)  NSInteger count;

@property(nonatomic,retain) UIImageView *imageVw;


@end


Second_View.m file
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

imageVw = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 200, 500, 400)];
imageVw.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"redacted2.jpg"];
imageVw.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
imageVw.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
imageVw.alpha = 0.93;  // for opacity
[self.view addSubview:imageVw];




tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[imageVw addGestureRecognizer:tap];
tap.delegate=self;
pan=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
[pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[pan setMaximumNumberOfTouches:2];
[pan setDelegate:self];
count=0;
[imageVw addGestureRecognizer:pan];



}


- (void)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer        translationInView:self.view];

if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer state] ==     UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
firstX = [[gestureRecognizer view] center].x;
firstY = [[gestureRecognizer view] center].y;
}


translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

[[gestureRecognizer view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer state] ==   UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
CGFloat velocityX = (0.2*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer     velocityInView:self.view].x);


CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + velocityX;
CGFloat finalY = firstY;// translatedPoint.y + (.35*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender    velocityInView:self.view].y);

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
if (finalX < 0) {
//finalX = 0;
} else if (finalX > 768) {
//finalX = 768;
}

if (finalY < 0) {
finalY = 0;
} else if (finalY > 1024) {
finalY = 1024;
}
} else {
if (finalX < 0) {
//finalX = 0;
} else if (finalX > 1024) {
//finalX = 768;
}

if (finalY < 0) {
finalY = 0;
} else if (finalY > 768) {
finalY = 1024;
}
}
}
}




-(void)handleTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

CGPoint location = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view];
NSLog(@"x:%f y:%f",location.x,location.y);


NSArray *subViewsOfImage = [imageVw subviews];


for (id subView in subViewsOfImage) {
CGRect frame1=[subView frame];
int x=0;
int y=0;
x=frame1.origin.x+frame1.size.width;
y=frame1.origin.y+frame1.size.height;

if ((location.x>=frame1.origin.x && location.x<x) && (location.y>=frame1.origin.y &&   location.y<y) )
{
NSLog(@"No");
return;
}
}


derivedView *view=[[derivedView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x, location.y, 100, 30)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[imageVw addSubview: view];
NSArray * subViewsOfImage1 = [imageVw subviews];
NSLog(@"subViewsOfImage = %@",subViewsOfImage1);
NSLog(@"Yes");

}
```

derivedView.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface derivedView : UIView<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
{
UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap1;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2;
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap3;
CGPoint lastLocation;
CGFloat firstX;
CGFloat firstY;
UIImageView *rPinImgView;
UIImageView *lPinImgView;

}

@end
```

derivedView.m file

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if (self) {
// Initialization code
pan=[[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panAction:)];
[pan setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:pan];
tap1=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapAction:)];
[tap1 setDelegate:self];
[self addGestureRecognizer:tap1];

}
return self;
}



- (void)tapAction:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {


//       lPinImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-15,-20, 30, 30)];
//    lPinImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
//    // pin.frame=CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x, frame1.origin.y-15, 10, 10);
//    
//    rPinImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake      (self.frame.size.width-15 ,23, 30, 30)];
//    //pin1.frame=CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x+frame1.size.width, frame1.origin.y+5, 10, 10);
//    rPinImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin1"];
//    [self addSubview:lPinImgView];
//    [self addSubview:rPinImgView];
NSArray *subViews=[self subviews];
NSLog(@"subViews%@",subViews);
if ([subViews count]>0) {
[lPinImgView removeFromSuperview];
[rPinImgView removeFromSuperview];
}else
{
lPinImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-15,-20, 30, 30)];
lPinImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin"];
// pin.frame=CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x, frame1.origin.y-15, 10, 10);

rPinImgView=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.frame.size.width-15 ,23, 30, 30)];
//pin1.frame=CGRectMake(frame1.origin.x+frame1.size.width, frame1.origin.y+5, 10, 10);
rPinImgView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"pin1"];
tap2=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector (rPinImageTap:)];
[rPinImgView addGestureRecognizer:tap2];
[tap2 setDelegate:self];
tap3=[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(lPinImageTap:)];
[rPinImgView addGestureRecognizer:tap3];
[tap3 setDelegate:self];
[self addSubview:lPinImgView];
[self addSubview:rPinImgView];

}


- (void)lPinImageTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

}
- (void)rPinImageTap:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

}
- (void)panAction:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer   translationInView:self];

if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer state] ==     UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
firstX = [[gestureRecognizer view] center].x;
firstY = [[gestureRecognizer view] center].y;
}

//  translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY);
translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

[[gestureRecognizer view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

if ([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer state] ==   UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
CGFloat velocityX = (0.2*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer   velocityInView:self].x);


CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + velocityX;
CGFloat finalY = firstY;// translatedPoint.y + (.35*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].y);

if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
if (finalX < 0) {
//finalX = 0;
} else if (finalX > 768) {
//finalX = 768;
}

if (finalY < 0) {
finalY = 0;
} else if (finalY > 1024) {
finalY = 1024;
}
} else {
if (finalX < 0) {
//finalX = 0;
} else if (finalX > 1024) {
//finalX = 768;
}

if (finalY < 0) {
finalY = 0;
} else if (finalY > 768) {
finalY = 1024;
}
}
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this below link and download the project and check:

https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView